# Mysql/Maria unique keys representation

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to know how keys stored in mysql/mariadb database.
As i know there are some types stored in information_schema.columns: *PRI*, *MUL* and *UNI* that means Primary Key, Key, and Unique Key respectively.

But it is not true.

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE test_table(leftkey int unsigned, rightkey int unsigned, unique key(leftkey, rightkey));

MariaDB [test]> DESC test_table;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| leftkey  | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| rightkey | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

So i have 2 questions:

**1) How do i detect that key type is Unique? Describe command shows that type is MUL, not UNI (that means simple key).**

**2) Where are key pair (in example: leftkey and rightkey) stored?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother with DESCRIBE, because as you have found, it gives ambiguous information in some cases.

Just use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. That will show exactly the SQL syntax that would recreate the table. Then you can know exactly which keys exist, and what type.

```
mysql> show create table test_table\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: test_table
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `leftkey` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `rightkey` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `leftkey` (`leftkey`,`rightkey`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

You can also query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS` to get more precise information.

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.statistics where table_name='test_table'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
TABLE_CATALOG: def
 TABLE_SCHEMA: test
   TABLE_NAME: test_table
   NON_UNIQUE: 0
 INDEX_SCHEMA: test
   INDEX_NAME: leftkey
 SEQ_IN_INDEX: 1
  COLUMN_NAME: leftkey
    COLLATION: A
  CARDINALITY: 0
     SUB_PART: NULL
       PACKED: NULL
     NULLABLE: YES
   INDEX_TYPE: BTREE
      COMMENT: 
INDEX_COMMENT: 
*************************** 2. row ***************************
TABLE_CATALOG: def
 TABLE_SCHEMA: test
   TABLE_NAME: test_table
   NON_UNIQUE: 0
 INDEX_SCHEMA: test
   INDEX_NAME: leftkey
 SEQ_IN_INDEX: 2
  COLUMN_NAME: rightkey
    COLLATION: A
  CARDINALITY: 0
     SUB_PART: NULL
       PACKED: NULL
     NULLABLE: YES
   INDEX_TYPE: BTREE
      COMMENT: 
INDEX_COMMENT:
```

Or the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` table has slightly different information:

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.key_column_usage where table_name = 'test_table'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           CONSTRAINT_CATALOG: def
            CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA: test
              CONSTRAINT_NAME: leftkey
                TABLE_CATALOG: def
                 TABLE_SCHEMA: test
                   TABLE_NAME: test_table
                  COLUMN_NAME: leftkey
             ORDINAL_POSITION: 1
POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT: NULL
      REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA: NULL
        REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME: NULL
       REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           CONSTRAINT_CATALOG: def
            CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA: test
              CONSTRAINT_NAME: leftkey
                TABLE_CATALOG: def
                 TABLE_SCHEMA: test
                   TABLE_NAME: test_table
                  COLUMN_NAME: rightkey
             ORDINAL_POSITION: 2
POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT: NULL
      REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA: NULL
        REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME: NULL
       REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME: NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

The `information_schema.columns` describes the columns not the keys which are constraints. Columns are used in constraints so you need to use some other `information_schema` tables to get information.

You can use the following query to get some more information about constraints:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE TK
 ON TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TK.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
 AND TC.TABLE_SCHEMA = TK.TABLE_SCHEMA
 AND TC.TABLE_NAME   = TK.TABLE_NAME
 AND TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```